# Left and right Divs in CSS

Tags: html, css, tags

I want a left div box, and a right div box. The right div shoulld be 300px wide and show right beside the left div.

I am awful with CSS, and despite trying solutions from 5 other stack overflow questions similer to this one, im still not able to figure it out.

I have tried display: inline;
I have tried tables/table cells.
I have tried fixed and auto margins
I have tried padding.
I have searched for the last hour and continued to tinker.

I am truly at my wits end with this stupid language and need help.

I have a news feed on my homepage, I simply want a 300px box on the right of my main article to show news. I have boiled it down to its most simple possible components to test solutions, and none of them appear to work at all.

My style.css:

```
#left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 400px;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 298px;
}
```

My HTML file:

```
<div id="right">
    Latest News
</div>
<div id="left">
    <p>My problem comes when this p tag gets too long. everything is ok when they are short, but regardless of wrapping, the look gets screwed the second this is too long and it is driving me bonkers.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Divs use `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Don't really understand the problem. What do you mean "the look gets screwed"?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this. The answers below already offer help with a few approaches. I really recommend you go through http://learnlayout.com/ to get a handle on css layout.

Comment: @gnubie The div's stack instead of being displayed side by side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply keep the `#left` block element as regular inflow content, not floated.

The right margin will provide the space for the news feed on the right to grow as needed.

```css
#left {
  margin-right: 320px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  width: 298px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="right">
  <h2>Latest News - Your news feed.</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>News topic ...</li>
    <li>News topic ...</li>
    <li>News topic ...</li>
    <li>News topic ...</li>
    <li>News topic ...</li>
    <li>News topic ...</li>
    <li>News topic ...</li>
    <li>News topic ...</li>
    <li>News topic ...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="left">
  <p>My problem comes when this p tag gets too long. everything is ok when they are short, but regardless of wrapping, the look gets screwed the second this is too long and it is driving me bonkers.</p>
  <p>My problem comes when this p tag gets too long. everything is ok when they are short, but regardless of wrapping, the look gets screwed the second this is too long and it is driving me bonkers.</p>
  <p>My problem comes when this p tag gets too long. everything is ok when they are short, but regardless of wrapping, the look gets screwed the second this is too long and it is driving me bonkers.</p>
  <p>My problem comes when this p tag gets too long. everything is ok when they are short, but regardless of wrapping, the look gets screwed the second this is too long and it is driving me bonkers.</p>
  <p>My problem comes when this p tag gets too long. everything is ok when they are short, but regardless of wrapping, the look gets screwed the second this is too long and it is driving me bonkers.</p>
  <p>My problem comes when this p tag gets too long. everything is ok when they are short, but regardless of wrapping, the look gets screwed the second this is too long and it is driving me bonkers.</p>
  <p>My problem comes when this p tag gets too long. everything is ok when they are short, but regardless of wrapping, the look gets screwed the second this is too long and it is driving me bonkers.</p>
  <p>My problem comes when this p tag gets too long. everything is ok when they are short, but regardless of wrapping, the look gets screwed the second this is too long and it is driving me bonkers.</p>
  <p>My problem comes when this p tag gets too long. everything is ok when they are short, but regardless of wrapping, the look gets screwed the second this is too long and it is driving me bonkers.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution worked for my test example, now i must slowly reverse engineer my actual files to make it work properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

HTML dividers use `display: inline-block;` not `display: inline;`.

HTML

```
<div id="right">
    Latest News
</div>
<div id="left">
    <p>My problem comes when this p tag gets too long. everything is ok   when they are short, but regardless of wrapping, the look gets screwed the second this is too long and it is driving me bonkers.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#left {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 400px;
}
#right {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 298px;
}
```

There is no need for `float: left;`. Dividers are naturally to the left of the page.

Comment: Your solution once tested shows the exact problem I have outlined. Yourr solution does not work.

Comment: It worked correctly in [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) though I am sorry to hear that it did not work for you.

Comment: It worked correctly when I tested your answer also. There is something else in your (Pyro's) code that you're not showing us, which is creating your problem. Also, a better explanation of what isn't working out for you would help us out better.

Comment: I tested the solution on a blank html file with a blank style.css and this solution showed the same div stacking which has been a problem for me. It very well could be my environment, but I removed all variables except the provided solution and could not achieve a working result.The problem I receive is the div's stack instead of being side by side. After implementing all solutions, in a blank test environment, only the third solution seems to have fixed the problem. There only sample code i used to test the solutions was in fact what i provided here.

Comment: If you can use `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;`, you can just add `right: 0;` (or any direction) to your #right/#left styles.

Comment: Also, your solution does not work in jsfiddle. It displays the very same problem i am looking for a solution to. http://jsfiddle.net/645c8792/